# Executing select statement as variable from TVF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have to get a list of results from a Table value function from a variable. I have done something like this:

```
DECLARE @Date char(8) = '20200508'
DECLARE @Type varchar(100) = 'Inbound'
DECLARE @Offset INT = 3600
DECLARE @EmployeeID INT = null

DECLARE @TypeFunc as varchar(max) 
SET @TypeFunc= N'select EmpID, Callcount from dbo.fn_' + @Type + '('''+ @Date +''','+ CAST(@Offset as Varchar(100))+','+ CAST(@EmployeeID as varchar(100))+')';
EXEC (@TypeFunc)
```

I expect to see a list of results as if I'm doing a normal select query, however, it is just coming back with **'Commands completed successfully.'** in the results grid, which doesn't seem like its doing it correctly.

The query it should run should look like

`Select EmpID, Callcount From dbo.fn_Inbound('20200508', 3600, null)`

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 mistakes in your Query:

1.) Use `CONCAT` instead of `+` because if any of your concatenating string is null it makes the whole Concatenation as NULL (For your case EmpID is null it will makes the Whole Query as null by using `+`)

2.)`ISNULL(CAST(@EmployeeID as varchar(100)),'NULL')` Use `ISNULL` fn to pass as null for that Parameter in your function

```
SET @TypeFunc= CONCAT(N'select EmpID, Callcount from dbo.fn_' , @Type , '(''', @Date 
,''',', CAST(@Offset as Varchar(100)),',',ISNULL(CAST(@EmployeeID as 
varchar(100)),'NULL'),')');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've now used Concat for similar queries also.